# Cyrillic and GhostScript

Tags: ghostscript, cyrillic

I am struggling to convert my PCL file to PDF using GhostScript. The conversion itself is not issue, but it appears that Cyrillic is problem. As you can see on attached picture, it considers only the colon and period symbol.

I tried different fonts and symbol sets, but I never got correct result.
I was also trying to convert cyrillic TTF to soft font via PCL Paraphernalia but I was not successfull with using the font in my PCL.

Using following command:

```
gpcl6win64.exe -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOCACHE -dRENDERTTNOTDEF -sOutputFile=output.pdf CYR.prn
```

My file:

[image]

PDF output:

[image]

Please advise.

Thank you

Comment: did u solve ur problem?

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, you have not supplied the font, or the font you are using does not contain Cyrillic glyphs. Colon and period are obviously going to be present in any Latin font, Cyrillic glyphs generally are not. Any glyphs not present in the font will be replaced by the /.notdef glyph, which is usually a non-marking glyph (except for TrueType fonts where it's usually a hollow square).

If that's your entire PCL file then I can't say I'm surprised it doesn't work as you expect, you haven't downloaded a font. I don't know PCL well enough to say exactly what that minimal file is doing but here's a thought: try using gpclwin64 to render the PCL to the display. If that doesn't work then there's no way it's going to result in a PDF file which works.

Basically you're going to have to download a soft font containing the glyphs you want to use encoded at the character codes you want to use.

NB: I'd strongly advise against using `-dNOCACHE` because that will hurt performance on large text-heavy files.

Comment: Hello Ken,

Thank you for your answer. I am new to PCL and it is not clear to me how to download soft font and use it in my PCL.
Based on what I found, Arial should support 118 cyrillic characters. For example if I open my file in EscapE from RedTitan, it is displayed correctly, using Arial font.

If you have any example how to download soft font, please share it with me. I did lot of searching and checked HP documentation on PCL, but couldn't find how to do it.

Comment: GhostPCL doesn't (I don't think) include an Arial font, it uses a substitute. I can't help you with downloading soft fonts as I know next to nothing about PCL. I suppose eht first question would be **why** are you using PCL ? If you want a PDF file there are easier ways to get one than starting with PCL.